# remove only the first blank line sed

Tags: sed

there are similar questions here but none matches my problem exactly.

How do I remove only the first blank line from a file using sed?

Let's say I have

```
a

b

c
```

And I want

```
a
b

c
```

As output.

Comment: Do you need to use `sed`? `awk 'a||$0;!$0{a=1}'`

Comment: @Kevin, `$0` resolve to false if the line is empty **or** resolves to a numerical 0 (like `00` or `0.0` or `0e12`...). Use `$0 != ""` instead. Test for `NF` for non-blank lines.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Right, not enough coffee. `awk 'a||NF;!NF{a=1}'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the `sed` FAQ [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.11):

```
$ sed '0,/^$/{//d}' lines
a
b

c

d
```

Note this only removes truly empty lines, if you want to consider lines with whitespace you would use

```
$ sed '0,/^[[:space:]]*$/{//d}' lines
```

instead.

Comment: That's not standard `sed` syntax though.

Comment: @Stephane The link states several non-GNU `sed` alternatives, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to read up to the first blank line, and then use `cat` to read the rest which would be the most efficient for big files:

```
{ sed -n '/./!q;p'; cat; } < the-file
```

It only works with regular files though (not with pipes because `sed` reads data by blocks and can't seek back to the line after the one where `q` was called if the input is not seekable). As noted by @peterph, With GNU `sed` version 4.2.2 and above, you can add the `-u` flag which causes GNU `sed` to read its input one byte at a time (and output one line at a time) and removes the problem with pipes (though degrading performance).

Comment: GNU sed (at least) has the `-u` option which should reduce buffering.

Comment: @peterph, with `-u`, GNU sed will still read data by blocks (4k according to `strace` with `sed` 4.2.1, eglibc 2.13, Linux amd64) so it won't help here. I've clarified what I meant by _buffering_.

Comment: GNU sed 4.2.2 does a 1B read here in `cat file | sed -u`.

Comment: @peterph, Indeed, that's a new feature added in 4.2.2 (see [commit log](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/sed/execute.c?id=737ca5ec59f739506e6fdc7eff53c62f6723fe3e))